# How i create stored procedure update only one set of rows...........?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  update_salary()   
BEGIN
UPDATE employee SET salary = salary*1.4 where e_desc =  'Senior Manager';

UPDATE employee SET salary = salary*1.2 where e_desc = 'Manager';

UPDATE employee SET salary = salary*1.1 where e_desc = 'Assistant manager';

End $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I create stored procedure to My_sql to update tables values. It is working but, I want to change this to update only one of set of rows.

e.g. When I give 'Manager' update only that column.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with an IF statement inside your stored procedure like so..

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  update_salary(IN employeeType VARCHAR(255))   
BEGIN
IF (employeeType = "Seinor Manager") THEN
    UPDATE employee SET salary = salary*1.4 where e_desc =  'Senior Manager';
ELSEIF (employeeType = "Manager") THEN
    UPDATE employee SET salary = salary*1.2 where e_desc = 'Manager';
ELSE
    UPDATE employee SET salary = salary*1.1 where e_desc = 'Assistant manager';
END IF;
End $$
DELIMITER ;
```

or you could do it with a case statement too if that suites you better

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  update_salary(IN employeeType VARCHAR(255))   
BEGIN
CASE employeeType
  WHEN "Seinor Manager") 
    THEN UPDATE employee SET salary = salary*1.4 where e_desc =  'Senior Manager';
  WHEN "Manager" 
    THEN UPDATE employee SET salary = salary*1.2 where e_desc = 'Manager';
  ELSE 
    UPDATE employee SET salary = salary*1.1 where e_desc = 'Assistant manager';
END;
End $$
DELIMITER ;
```